# How parse json data array inside and add to ObservableCollection using C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my json data

```html
{
 "found": 501,
 "posts": [
   {
   "ID": 2500,
   "site_ID": 1,
   "date": "2014-09-26T15:58:23-10:00",
   "modified": "2014-09-26T15:58:23-10:00",
   "title": "DOD HQ Visitors Parking",
   "metadata": [
    {
     "id": "15064",
     "key": "city",
     "value": "Honolulu County"
    },
    {
     "id": "15067",
     "key": "country",
     "value": "US"
    },
    {
     "id": "15062",
     "key": "floor_level",
     "value": "Ground Floor"
    }
    ]
   }
  ],
  "_headers": {
  "Date": "Fri, 13 Feb 2015 09:21:55 GMT",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
}
```

I used model class generated from http://json2csharp.com/

```html
public class Metadata
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int site_ID { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string modified { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Metadata> metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Headers
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__Content-Type { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int found { get; set; }
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
    public Headers _headers { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way of Parsing JSON array, I want to put the data collected into a ObservableCollection to be used in binding my Listview in XAML Page.

```html
public class SpacesViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Space> Spaces { get; set; }

        public SpacesViewModel()
        {
            Spaces = new ObservableCollection<Space>();
            this.LoadSpaces();
        }

        async private void LoadSpaces()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/allspaces.json");
            var resultObjects = AllChildren(JObject.Parse(json))
                .First(c => c.Type == JTokenType.Array && c.Path.Contains("posts"))
                .Children<JObject>();
            
            foreach (JObject post in resultObjects)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(post["title"]);
                foreach (var metadata in post["metadata"])
                {
                    var key = metadata["key"].ToString();
                    if (key == "city")
                        Debug.WriteLine(metadata["value"].ToString());

                    if (key == "street_address")
                        Debug.WriteLine(metadata["value"].ToString());
                }
             }
          }

        private static IEnumerable<JToken> AllChildren(JToken json)
        {
            foreach (var c in json.Children())
            {
                yield return c;
                foreach (var cc in AllChildren(c))
                {
                    yield return cc;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use the [Newtonsofts Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) libary. You can easily get it as nuget. After adding the nuget you can simply parse a collection (nested collections are working as well) with:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

string json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/allspaces.json");
List<Post> parsedPosts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(json);
```

After getting the posts as `List`, you can add them to your `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Yes I'm using Newtonsoft.Json library, I follow another approach from this post in xamarin forums [link] (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37195/json-to-observablecollection-to-be-used-on-listview#latest)

Comment: Yes I'm using Newtonsoft.Json library, I follow another approach from this post in xamarin forums [link] (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37195/json-to-observablecollection-to-be-used-on-listview#latest) 

This are my codes, I follow the MVVM pattern.

Model http://pastebin.com/HPyms0Dk - please correct me if I'm wrong.

ViewModel http://pastebin.com/sMCsbsFh

And XAMLView http://pastebin.com/6B0pcMD5

Kindly show me how to get posts as List, I'm new with C# and Xamarin. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You mixed View and ViewModel a little. Try to bind the View to your ViewModel and not to your View (done with the BindinContext). Have a look at https://www.mallibone.com/post/xamarin.forms-and-mvvm there is an example with an collection.

Comment: How about the data inside my metadata? I want to implement separate bindings to the "city" and "country" values?